# Is `bash --posix` necessary for bash 4, when transmitting `set` options to subshells?

Tags: bash, shell-script

For example, does

```
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit -o noglob -o posix
```

apply to subshells in bash4 for any sub-version? From what I've read online and in the bash reference, `set -e`, AKA `set -o errexit` may apply to certain subshells such as command substitutions. The problem is that the documentation is not super transparent, and it's harder to devise appropriate tests for bash than some other programming languages.

Comment: The behaviour of `set -e` varies from version to version and shell to shell and is generally unpredictable. I would stay clear of it and do proper error handling by hand.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Ah thanks a ton. I found a lot of users that recommended its use, but I've had nothing but frustrations with it lately. Glad to know I'm not the only one.